# Conflicting css rules

Tags: html, css

I found this cool css scroll functionality created by someone else online and thought it would be cool to impliment it into some part of my extension I am creating. This is the first time really working with css and js so I am still trying to understand how everything works. The problem I am having is I found that some of the css for the scrolling is interfering with the `ul li` elements of my tabs, thus messing up the layout of the page.

This is the css part of the scroll view I found is the culpret.

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 230px;
    height: px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;

    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
       -moz-perspective: 400px;
        -ms-perspective: 400px;
         -o-perspective: 400px;
            perspective: 400px;
}
    ul li {
        position: relative;
        padding: 16px;
        background: #eee;
        color: #252525;
        font-size: 18px;
        z-index: 2;

        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
           -moz-transform: translateZ(0px);
            -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
             -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
                transform: translateZ(0px);
    }
```

and this is my small css for the tabs I am using (its inside html):

```
        <ul class="tab-links" style="
           margin-bottom: 0px;
           padding-left: 0px;
           margin-top: 0px;
           ">
           <li class="" style="
              margin-left: 0px;
              margin-right: 6.875;
              "><a href="#tab1" style="
              width: 60px;
              ">New</a></li>
           <li class="active" style="
              margin-left: 6.875;
              margin-right: 6.875;
              "><a href="#tab2" style="
              width: 60px;
              ">Existing</a></li>
           <li class="" style="
              margin-right: 0px;
              margin-left: 6.875;
              "><a href="#tab3" style="
              width: 60px;
              ">Passport</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I can see why the problem is happening, they are both taking the styles of the imported scroll view rather than their respective rules, but with my limited knowledge I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: inline `style="..."` rules will always override styles specified elsewhere (`<link>`, `<style>`), unless the "elsewhere" styles have `!important` overrides on them.

Comment: So, you want this specific `ul` not to inherit the css styles?

Comment: the bottom section deals with the styles of the tabs (there are three at the top). The top section deals with the elements inside of a scrolling view INSIDE of tab #2, but the tabs are getting the traits of the individual pieces of the scrolling view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your "scroll" ul, eg:

```
<ul class="scroll"...
```

Then change the CSS selectors to

```
ul.scroll {...

ul.scroll li {...
```

Now that CSS will only apply ul elements with the "scroll" class and their children.

Comment: `<ul class="scroll foo dong">` you can have multiple classes.